# Volume of the sphere in a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis

For $n > 1$ an integer, there are well-known formulas for volume of the balls.

What is the analogous statement in a Banach space/Hilbert Space?

Comment: There is no analogue of the volume form for an infinite-dimensional space, since there is no top exterior power.  So what does "volume" mean here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful, a formula for the [volume of Lp balls in R^n](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/07/02/volumes-of-generalized-unit-balls/).

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  The L^p ball is not the L^p analogue of a simplex.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I was seeding the site with questions and forgot what exact answer I wanted to bait; so I was too vague. Sorry. Now I modified the question.

Answer (score 6):

In an infinite-dimensional normed space with a translation-invariant measure, the measure of a ball must be either $0$ or $\infty$.  This fact is sometimes summarized as "[there is no infinite-dimensional Lebesgue measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_no_infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure)."  So unless you have some other notion of "volume" in mind, only the finite-dimensional case (i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n$ with some other norm) has any content.  And with regard to Hilbert spaces, the only finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean inner product, so of course we know about this.

Answer (score 1):

A finite measure $\mu$ on a separable complete metric space has the property of tightness; i.e. for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some compact subset $K$ so that $\mu(K^c) < \epsilon$.   A  Banach space that is locally compact is necessarily finite dimensional.  Hence, a compact subset is a very small subset that must have a  void interior.